# Spring Boot POST request with missing request body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a very simple HTML form page (which is a part of Spring Boot web application in src/main/resources/public/web.html) to post a String from a textarea to a Spring Boot web application version 1.5.2.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea cols="128" rows="40" name="query"></textarea>
<input value="Send" type="submit">
</form>
```

And the SpringBoot class to handle the POST request:

```
@RestController
public class QueryController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/handle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected void handlePost(@RequestBody String postBody) throws Exception {
       // Get query from postBody here
    }
}
```

It works with small String from textarea in client. However, when the String is big (e.g: with HTTP request header: Content-Length:3789333 (3 MB)). Spring Boot throws an exception like this:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: protected void QueryController.handlePost(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:154)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
```

I'm not sure what causes this problem, I'm running the web application with embedded Tomcat from Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but could this be caused by missing the encoding of the content?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is @RequestBody cannot get value for the big query. However, get request body from HttpServletRequest it  can get value

```
 protected void handlePost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws Exception {
    String postBody = this.getPOSTRequestBody(httpServletRequest); 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your contoller to following:

```
@RestController
public class QueryController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/handle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected void handlePost(@RequestParam(value="query",required=false) String query) throws Exception {
       // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

If you do not pass paramater you will get `org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'query' is not present`. If paramater not required you can add `required=false` to `RequestParam`. By default `required=true` for RequestParam.

It depends to your server. I hope your are using `Tomcat`. By default server has `maxPostSize`. The following is for Tomcat

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxPostSize="6291456" />
```

`maxPostSize` is 6MB in my preceding code.

Comment: Another error only when POST is big

] ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver@189: Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.lang.NullPointerException
 ERROR [09:39:24] ExceptionAdvice@57: Catched an exception: 
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'query' is not present

Comment: With big query, the query value is null, it doesn't help.

Comment: It doesn't work either, thanks for your trying, I'm not uploading file.

Comment: `maxPostSize` did not help?